# using controlname.clientID and only control name in javascript getelementbyID method

Tags: javascript, asp.net, user-controls, custom-controls

I have custom compound control which I want to disable. the custom control consist of a text-field and calender control. I want to disable the image and the textfield both.
here is how it is referenced in the page.

control name is datepicker

```
 <control:DatePicker ID="dpDOB" runat="server" Title="Date of Birth" TextBoxCssClass="calendartxtS0" TitlePosition="Left" TitleBold="true" />
```

I can disable it like this.

```
document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder___Page_EventOrganiserSearch_dpDOB_imgBtn").disabled = true;
```

Comment: What is your question then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surround your control with div (for example) and disable div.

Please remember about potential vulnerability if user simply enable your control with Firebug-like tools.

Regards.